# How do I create a function for checking the wincon for connect 4?

Tags: python

I have read multiple forums on connect 4 and functions for checking to win but I have never found an appropriate solution for my code.

Here is the code:

```
board = [['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.'],
         ['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.'],
         ['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.'],
         ['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.'],
         ['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.'],
         ['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.']
         ]


def printboard():
    """Prints the board"""
    print('\n'.join(['\t'.join([str(cell) for cell in row]) for row in board]))


def placement(tokentype):
    """Function to place tokens and stack"""
    for i in range(5, -1, -1):
        if board[i][column - 1] != '.':
            pass
        elif board[i][column - 1] == '.':
            board[i][column - 1] = tokentype
            break

tokenTypes = ['x', 'o']

while True:
    column = int(input("Player 1, what column do you want to place your token in? "))
    placement(tokenTypes[0])
    printboard()
    column = int(input("Player 2, what column do you want to place your token in?"))
    placement(tokenTypes[1])
    printboard()
```

Comment: There's no way except brute force.  Have separate functions for horizontal, vertical, and diagonal checks.  Remember that on a 6x6 board, every vertical win will start in row 0, 1, or 2, and every horizontal win will start in column 0, 1, or 2.  I'll post an answer for checking for horizontal.  The rest is left as an exercise for the reader.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the code for checking for horizontal winners.  The check for vertical winners is almost the same.  Diagonal is a just bit tricker.  Remember diagonals go both ways.

```
def check_horizontal_winner(board):
    for row in range(6):
        for col in range(3):
            if board[row][col] != '.' and \
                 board[row][col] == board[row][col+1] == \
                 board[row][col+2] == board[row][col+3]:
                 print( "WINNER", board[row][col], "starting at", row, col )
                 return board[row][col]
    return None
```

Your placement code is a little silly.  You don't need the 'if' part at all.  And, of course, you need to pass in the column:

```
def placement(tokentype, column):
    """Function to place tokens and stack"""
    for i in range(5, -1, -1):
        if board[i][column - 1] == '.':
            board[i][column - 1] = tokentype
            break
```

**EDIT to add diagonal checks**

Consider that a "/" diagonal (lower left towards upper right) can only begin in x=0..3, y=0..3.  The only tricky thing here is that a  downward "\" diagonal will start in the upper half (x=0..3, y=4..6).  That could easily be done with two sets of loops, but I just defined a separate variable (`trow`) that counts from the top down.

You could probably combine all three of these functions into one.  It might be very slightly faster, but I think it would be more confusing to read.

```
def check_diagonal_winner( board ):
    for row in range(3):
        trow = len(board) - 1 - row
        for col in range(3):
            if board[row][col] == '.':
                continue
            # Check for a / diagonal.
            if board[row][col] == board[row+1][col+1] ==  \
                board[row+2][col+2] == board[row+3][col+3]:
                print( "WINNER", board[row][col], "starting at", row, col )
                break
            # Check for a  \ diagonal.  We check from the top down.
            if board[trow][col] == board[trow-1][col+1] ==  \
                board[trow-2][col+2] == board[trow-3][col+3]:
                print( "WINNER", board[trow][col], "starting at", trow, col )
                break
```

Comment: You are an amazing person, tysm.

Comment: I've almost done the diagonal function but it's just the parameters for the for loops that are messing me up. Could you help?

Comment: It is a bit tricky.  I'll modify my answer to add that.